# how to design the table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to add some data into a table for cms, the data's output on the frontend is as this:

```
one year  $100
two years  $260
three years  $350
500 accounts $360/m
1500 accounts $660/m
2500 accounts $960/m
```

the backend is a form. the price part is inputted by the editor. i want to put the 100,260,350....namely, the price part into a table. but i don't know how design the table.  how to make each price have a relationship with the front label.then in my programme i can invoke them.

Comment: are there any relations between the prices per year and the account-informations? I think, your post is a bit to abstract. Write down in one row, what kind of informations / which attributes you like to save in the database. So 50% of the table-design are ready. Which database you are using (important if relations could be an option)

Comment: i am a new to php. i want to do a form,which likes the above and put the price part in database. how to write the table?

Comment: what do you want to know? How to write into a table? Or how to design the table. These are 2 different things. The 1st is a question of programming / coding. The 2nd is a question of application design before - start writing program-code.

Comment: how to design the table? thank you

Comment: what are the relation between "one year  $100" and "500 accounts $360/m" what does /m mean? Tell me more about your needs so i can create an table design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label (product name) and price are obviously related, just like any other product and its price. I would simply make a table called products, which would have the columns 'id', 'product', 'price'. Then I'd populate the table with the following:

```
INSERT INTO product (id, product, price) VALUES (null, 'One Year', '$100');
INSERT INTO product (id, product, price) VALUES (null, 'Two Years', '$260');
INSERT INTO product (id, product, price) VALUES (null, 'Three Years', '$350');
```

I'd then let the backend editor simply give admins access to edit that table, and have the frontend to simply list the content of the table.

If the 'year' prices are a different type of product that then 'account' prices, then i'd consider a 'category' column in the 'product' table where you could differentiate between products'. So, if you just would like to list 'year' prices, you could filter on the 'category' column.

Anyway, I'd skip "hardcoding" the labels on the frontend and only store the prices. I'd rather keep the labels and prices together so that it is easier to change. It is so much easier to change the day you would like to introduce a new price level or change an existing one.